# gcc is not present in /usr/bin. How to install it in RHEL 7?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, gcc

Accidentally I have removed the gcc executable file from /usr/bin in RHEL 7.

Now when I want to check the version of gcc I get nothing in the output.

Tried:

> yum install gcc - NO OUTPUT
>
> yum install gcc gcc-c++ - NO OUTPUT

I am not able to compile any program anymore. How do I get the gcc executable file?
Thanks

Edit:

Output: rpm -qa | grep gcc

```
kanassu@server1$ rpm -qa | grep gcc

devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran-6.3.1-3.1.el7.x86_64
compat-gcc-44-c++-4.4.7-8.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc-c++-6.3.1-3.1.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc-6.3.1-3.1.el7.x86_64
libgcc-4.8.5-28.el7.i686
gcc-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64
compat-gcc-44-4.4.7-8.el7.x86_64
libgcc-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64
```

Output: rpm -V yum

```
kanassu@server1$ rpm -V yum
S.5....T.    /usr/bin/yum
```

Output: rpm -q yum

```
kanassu@server1$ rpm -q yum
yum-3.4.3-154.el7.noarch
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting ?

Comment: Please, be more clear/concise/specific about what is going on (expected behavior, if there's errors, the context...)

Comment: There is no error. Previously "yum install gcc" gave the version that was installed. But now there is not output. The cursor goes to the next line. 

user@server$ yum install gcc
user@server$

Comment: Have you tried `yum reinstall gcc` ?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes. Give no output.

Comment: Does `yum list available` give any output?

Comment: @NasirRiley. No . I think 'yum' is not working.

Comment: What about the results of `rpm -qa | grep gcc`?

Comment: Also, post the output of `rpm -V yum`

Comment: @jsbillings- 
Added the output

Answer (score 1):

```
kanassu@server1$ rpm -V yum
S.5....T.    /usr/bin/yum
```

This `rpm -V yum` output indicates that the size, cryptographic hash and modification time of your `yum` executable are not what they should be. It may have been damaged, or your system may have been hacked into and rootkitted. The fact that there are no error messages makes me worry that the later option might be true.

If you suspect your system has been hacked, see [what to do if your system is compromised](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231) on Information Security StackExchange.

But if you are convinced it's simply damage, you should download from access.redhat.com (or copy from your installation media) a good version of `yum-3.4.3-154.el7.noarch.rpm` and use a command like

```
sudo rpm --reinstall /path/to/yum-3.4.3-154.el7.noarch.rpm
```

to repair it by reinstalling a good version over the bad one.

Comment: Can you provide a link for yum-3.4.3-154.el7.noarch.rpm package download?
I checked access.redhat.com but was not able to find the package.

Comment: It requires a RedHat account. access.redhat.com -> downloads -> RPM Package Search (right sidebar) -> (login if not already logged in) -> keyword = "yum", product = Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64 (or whatever) -> select the blue "noarch" button on the "yum" line -> select Version 3.4.3.154.el7 -> scroll down -> click on "Download Now".

Comment: If I go to RPM Package Search-> Active Subscription required. I have already logged in.
Is there any other site I can download the rpm package?

Comment: @Kanassu RHEL requires a subscription to get software from accesss.redhat.com. I suggest finding whatever installation medium (ISO images or DVDs) and find the package on it.

Comment: Actually I re-imaged the server entirely because of the subscription issue. Thanks for your help.